# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawAxis'

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ros, aruco

I am working with ros melodic, opencv 4.5.5, ubuntu 18.04. I draw 3 axis of marker aruco to display on rqt_image_view. when running i get this problem *AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawAxis'*
Here is the code of my axis plot:

```
 ......................
    frame_out = aruco.drawAxis( img, self.K, self.distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, axisLength)
    ...................
    self.aruco_marker_img_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame_out, "bgr8"))
    .......................
```

when i do aruco aruco without ros it's normal,when it's right it will look like this

[image]

Comment: Could you try printing out `aruco.__file__` using `print(armco.__file__)`? I think python could be mistaking a local module with the same name as `aruco` module?

Comment: Does this help frame_out = cv2.aruco.drawAxis instead of frame_out = aruco.drawAxis?

Comment: I realized that cv2.aruco.drawAxis can't compile in python2 but that conflicts with the tf package. how can i compile tf package with python3

Comment: Are u using python2?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `cv2.drawFrameAxes` instead of `cv2.drawAxes`.